# ¿Cómo validar un campo mediante una expresión regular?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo un campo en el cual quiero guardar una dirección, y quiero agregarle la siguiente expresión regular:  `[CL.,CR.,AV.].[0-9] * # [0-9] * - [0-9] * . *`.

¿Dónde debo validar el campo, en el modelo o en el formulario? ¿Cómo debo hacerlo?

Este es mi modelo:

```
class PersonaBase(models.Model):
    direccion_residencia = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, 
    verbose_name=_("direccion"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`RegexValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#regexvalidator):

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class PersonaBase(models.Model):
    direccion_residencia = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        verbose_name=_("direccion"),
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(regex=r"[CL.,CR.,AV.].[0-9]* # [0-9] * - [0-9] * . *", message="Dirección inválida")
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Si bien estás respondiendo a la pregunta, el hecho de que tenga `[CL.,CR.,AV.]` o `" * "` hace evidente que tiene otros problemas además de cómo generar el validador.

Answer (score 1):

debes usar los [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators)

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

---

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    even_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])
```